# Plugin version is not showing up in wordpress.org plugin directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have developed A WordPress plugin. After updating it, it is not showing the WordPress version at wordpress.org plugin list.

wordpress.org URL:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/mail2users/

SVN URL: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/mail2users/

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress plugin repository always starts with what is in trunk. It reads down to the "Stable Tag" label. If the stable tag is "trunk" it continues reading from trunk. This is what people who download your plugin will get.

If, however, the stable tag label is a tag (in this case, 1.0.7), it quits reading trunk and goes to that tag directory and reads from there. This is what people who download your plugin will get.

If you are adding a new tagged version, you need to add that directory to tag, and then update the stable tag in trunk. You also need to give the repository a few minutes to update. Changes are not immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes struggled with the proper placement of plugins folder structure in Subversion. The process that works for me:

- base (root) folder of your plugin folder: the ZIP and uncompressed files of your latest version of the plugin
- the 'trunk' folder : ZIP + uncompressed files of latest version
- the 'tag' folder: create a subfolder that matches the 'Version" Parameter in your plugin header, then put the ZIP/Uncompressed files in there.

Do this on your local Subversion folder, then SVN Commit up to the WordPRess Subversion area , then SVN Update to get the versioning synced to your local Subversion area.

This is what has worked for me; I suspect there might be some fine-tuning needed (like not needing the uncompressed files everywhere..)